# get text content of an element by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get content of my dt s an set them as value attr of input.
this is my code.

//Html/php inline

```
$c=1;
          while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($usersQryResult)){
            echo"
                <tr>
                    <td>$c</td>
                    <td>$user[user]</td>
                    <td>$user[pass]</td>
                    <td>$user[email]</td>
                    <td>$user[level]</td>
                    <td>$user[status]</td>
                    <td>$user[lastlogin]</td>
                    <td><i onclick=\"editUser($user[id],this)\" class='fa fa-pencil-square-o' title='edit user info'></i></td>
                    <td><i onclick=\"deleteUser($user[id],this)\" class='fa fa-trash-o deletUser' title='remove user' ></i></td>                    
                </tr>
            ";
            $c++;
```

//js/jquery

```
function editUser(id,thisObj){
  var contents=$(thisObj).parent().siblings().text();
  $("#chUserName").val(contents[1]);
  $("#chUserPass").val(contents[2]);
  $("#chUserEmail").val(contents[5]);
}
```

but `contens[1]`,`contents[2]`,`content[3]` return 3 characters of my userName: for example: "Hamid" . will return H  a m !!!?/

Comment: Try `var contents = $(thisObj).parent().siblings().map(function() { return $(this).text(); });`

Comment: thanks, it works. why its not possible to directly access to its content??

Comment: Because `.html()` will take all the HTML of your siblings and put it together, returning one big HTML string. When you try to access the string, you'll get single characters back.

Comment: i also  used text () . but it returns H a m charecter of userName! var contents=$(thisObj).parent().siblings().text();

Comment: Yes, the same thing will happen, but with text instead of HTML. `.text()` will take all the text of all your siblings and put it together, returning one big string. When you try to access the string, you'll get single characters back.

Comment: ok. tnx alot. it doesen  work as an array. I thought it act as an array, and keep each sibling text seperately.

Comment: `.parent().siblings().text()` really makes no sense ... `.siblings()` returns an _array_ of DOM nodes (really a jQuery object, not a plain js array) and `.text()` returns _all of the text_ from them. So `contents` is just a really long String, which is why `contents[1]` returns just one character. Maybe what you really want is something more like `var contents = $(thisObj).parent().siblings(); $("#chUserName").val( contents[1].text() )` using the text of sibling number 1 as the new value of chUserName.

Answer (score 1):

I will recomend that you assing a class to each `<td>` that way you can reffer to each `<td>` directly within the context of the parent. Something like this:

```
<td class="user">$user[user]</td>
<td class="password">$user[pass]</td>
<td class="email">$user[email]</td>
<td class="level">$user[level]</td>
<td class="status">$user[status]</td>
```

And then, your JS could be something like this:

```
function editUser(id,thisObj){
var context=$(thisObj).patent().parent();
$("#chUserName").val($(".user",context).text());
$("#chUserPass").val($(".password",context).text());
$("#chUserEmail").val($(".email",context).text());
```

Comment: You're not even using `contents` here... What's the point of it?

Comment: Still, the solution could be much simpler... See my comment on the question.

Comment: yes, its possible too, but it may that i have more than one table.

Comment: @Hamid Why does that matter? Ricardo is using a specific context.

Comment: The context allow you to select a class (eg: email) from a specific <tr>. You just have to have the object that represents the <tr>. In this case is the "context" var.

Comment: @Hamid - Using a class on each also makes them independent of the order. In your original JS if you change the order of the columns in the table you also have to re-write your JS to use different indexes, but this code wouldn't have to change at all.

Comment: @Ricardo - if `thisObj` is the thing that was clicked, you'd need `thisObj.parent().parent()` to get the tr, because thisObj is the _content_ of the td so .parent() is the td itself. Or you could use `context = $(thisObj).closest('tr')` to climb the DOM tree to the first tr found.